# Messaging queue : paralellism and ordering

Tags: message-queue, worker

From one message queue containing orders (queued by users) and a bunch of workers taking messages from that queue and processing them :

I would like to ensure that the orders are processed in parallel when users are different, but sequentialy when they are queues from the same user.

For example :

- message_from_alex_1
- message_from_david_1
- message_from_alex_2
- message_from_david_2
- message_from_thomas_1

The process sequence should ensure that message_from_alex_1 is always processed before message_from_alex_2 and message_from_david_1 always before message_from_david_2.

Any hint ?